# Scala play json reader and writer for a type with a field of the same type

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.5

I'm newbie in scala programming. I want to define a writer and reader for a custom type.

I have the following classes:

```
case class Usuario(id:Int, userName: String, password: String, nombre: String, apellidos:String, correo: String,
                   nacimiento: Date, ciudad: String, pais: String, timetag: Long)

object Usuario{

  import play.api.libs.json._

  val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  implicit val dateWriter = play.api.libs.json.Writes.dateWrites(dateFormat)

  implicit val usuarioWrites = Json.writes[Usuario]
  implicit val usuarioReads = Json.reads[Usuario]

}
```

And

```
case class Equipo(id:Int, nombre:String, direccion: String, ciudad: String, equipoM:Equipo, usuario: Usuario, timetag: Long)

object Models {
  import play.api.libs.json._


  val dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  implicit val dateWriter = play.api.libs.json.Writes.dateWrites(dateFormat)

  implicit val equipoWrites = Json.writes[Equipo]
  implicit val equipoReads = Json.reads[Equipo]
}
```

For the first class, `Usuario`, everything works well. The second class, `Equipo`, does not.

The compiler error is:

> Error:(39, 42) No implicit format for models.Equipo available.
>   implicit val equipoWrites = Json.writes[Equipo]
>
> Error:(40, 40) No implicit format for models.Equipo available.
>   implicit val equipoReads = Json.reads[Equipo]

Maybe a nested class is not avalaible for an automated writer and reader. Does it exist any alternative for creating a Json writer and reader for a class with the field of the same type?.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Play json 2.6 for recursive support

Comment: Great wisdom @cchantep. Put it in a answer and i'll accept it